# Fastest way to calculate the last working page for scraping

Tags: javascript, algorithm, web-scraping, pagination

I'm trying to scrape a website and I don't want to be forced to recursively scrape every page until the "end".

I want to be able to just get the last page, or any page in between.

This isn't an issue most of the time, but this webpage is different. For example:

I do a search query on: "Logitech"

The website returns the following information I want to use:

- Total amount of products found: **15.000**
- Products per page: **30**
- Pagination: **1, 2, 3, 4, ...500** *(15.000/30 = 500)*

However it seems like the **Total amount of products found** is false information, and so is the pagination, because when I try to access `https://website.com/products?q=Logitech&page=500` there are no products. This also applies on lower values like: 499, 498, 450, 400, 350, etc.

So I tried "calculating" possible page numbers in my head, and I came down to **the actual last page number: 166**

I "calculated" this by checking if there were results:

- If there were results: increment value by amount x
- If there were no results: decrement value by amount x

So I made a **test script** to sort of replicate my method of finding the page number (repl.it link):
https://repl.it/@SaltyPotato1/LastPageCalculator

But I have two problems with his script (and I hope you guys can help me out):

1. This script "knows" the right value (**166**), so it can use `>` and `<` operators, when I'm scraping; It can only check if there is a **result** in this case: products. This means that there are only 2 options:

   - If there is a result it will mean that: the page number is either **too low** **or** it's in fact the last page number.
   - If there is **no result** it will mean that: the page number is **too** high.
2. I have a feeling the script/calculating could be improved, since some values are emitted twice.

What can I do to determine if it is in fact the **last page number** instead of a page number "under" the actual last page. And how could I minimize the amount of requests that are going to be made to calculate this.

I'm looking forward to your answers/help!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are not supposed to know all the page numbers for all kind of products. What you need is use the binary search algorithm to find the correct max page count. For which I suggest using HTTP Head request just to check whether that route exists, if the server doesn't support that method, you may try to do get request and just check the response's http status code, this way you don't need to do complex computation / dom query just for finding out correct max page count.

There will be slight change to your code.

```
function findMaxPageCount(totalProductCount = 1000, productPerPage = 1){
  const lo = 1;
  const hi = totalProductCount/productPage;
  let mid;
  let actualMaxPage = -1;
  while(lo <= hi){
    mid = Math.floor((lo + hi)/2.0);

    if(pageExists(mid)){
      actualMaxPage = mid;
      lo = mid + 1;
    }else{
      hi = mid - 1;
    }
  }

  return actualMaxPage;
}
```

The above method, will not search same page again, so read count is minimal and at most `Math.ceil(log2(totalProductCount/productPage))`.

Comment: Hi, there is an issue with the code though. I don't know what it is, but when the last page would (for example) be: 170 with max page value: 424. It will return the wrong value: 169 instead of 170, this is with almost every value that does not end with 6

Comment: sorry, code is fixed now. should work for every case.